# Keyboard and TextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

From Google Translate:

Hello, when I click on a text field, I made some modifications to a picker view appears.

When I navigate from text field to text field without touching on the "Done" button and I went to a text field that contains a picker view and that, I press done, the scroll view does not return to its original size .

Do you know how to please?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 974)];
    [ScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
      
    //on abonne notre instance aux notifications du clavier lorsqu'il apparaît et lorsqu'il disparait
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
  
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    //si le clavier est déjà présent on ne fait rien
    if (keyboardIsShown) {
        return;
    }
      
    if (nom.editing == YES)
    {
        //on récupère la taille du clavier
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGRect _keyboardEndFrame;
        [[info valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&_keyboardEndFrame];
        CGSize keyboardSize = _keyboardEndFrame.size;
      
        //on crée une nouvelle frame pour la scrollView
        CGRect viewFrame = self.ScrollView.frame;
        viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
      
        //on redimensionne la scrollView dans une animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [self.ScrollView setFrame:viewFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
      
        //on scroll jusqu'au champs texte en cours d'édition
        CGRect textFieldRect = nom.frame;
        [self.ScrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];
      
        //on enregistre l'état actuel du clavier
        keyboardIsShown = YES;
    }
      
    else if (dateVol.editing == YES)
    {
        //on récupère la taille du clavier
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGRect _keyboardEndFrame;
        [[info valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&_keyboardEndFrame];
        CGSize keyboardSize = _keyboardEndFrame.size;
          
        //on crée une nouvelle frame pour la scrollView
        CGRect viewFrame = self.ScrollView.frame;
        viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
          
        //on redimensionne la scrollView dans une animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [self.ScrollView setFrame:viewFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
          
        //on scroll jusqu'au champs texte en cours d'édition
        CGRect textFieldRect = prenom.frame;
        [self.ScrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];
          
        //on enregistre l'état actuel du clavier
        keyboardIsShown = YES;
    }
 }
  
//méthode appelée lorsque le clavier disparaît (on quitte l'édition d'un champs texte)
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
      
    if (nom.editing == YES || dateVol.editing == YES)
    {
        //get the size of the keyboard
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGRect _keyboardEndFrame;
        [[info valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&_keyboardEndFrame];
        CGSize keyboardSize = _keyboardEndFrame.size;
      
        //resize the scroll view
        CGRect viewFrame = self.ScrollView.frame;
        viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;
      
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [self.ScrollView setFrame:viewFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
      
        keyboardIsShown = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your question in English?

Comment: Anglais s'il vous plaît (English please).

Comment: Either you are doing something really weird to put a `UIPickerView` in a `UITextField` or Google Translate didn't work too well.  I'm assuming the latter and asking my friend if she can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are saying that you have set the `inputView` of a UITextField to a UIPickerView, and that when you hit Done after using the UIPickerView the scrollview is not returning to its previous location. Looking at your code, I think this is because your `keyboardWillHide` method is only called when a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is sent by the system. I assume that the system is not sending a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` when you are pressing the Done button. You need to add code to whatever method is called when you press the Done button that will call your `keyboardWillHide` method.

Comment: Yes, I think it's that, but what is the code for this please ? Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Does the Done button make your UIPickerView disappear? If so, you should have some code somewhere the sends `resignFirstResponder` to you UITextField when that happens. Add

Comment: like so: `[myTextField resignFirstResponder];`.  It is what you use to make the keyboard go away under normal circumstances.

Comment: Look my problem in this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcmYrkgAv5M&feature=youtu.be